# what are the commands executed in every click in windows?

Tags: c++, batch-file

As some suggested, I'm trying to minimize the question and get out of the web. That web example was not exactly what I wanted. I simply wanted to make a macro. Like if a condition is true open date settings and change the date to December 2000. If false, open time settings. How can I program to do this? Do I need to execute some commands in command prompt window to do it? If yes what are they? Actually, I want to make a macro that will do a lot of work in just on click.

as far as I know, eveything we do in computer or windows just executes a series of commands depending on the input of mouse and keyboard. So, I want to know if it is possible to know what commands are being executed in background. Actually, I want to make a macro in my program. As for example, a program that will go to google, search for a word and download the first imahe that comes from the search. If, it is possible to know then how.

[I could have searched in google. but I just couldn't guess what keywords to use in the search. so, I posted here. I am sorry if it has already been dicussed]

Comment: May be check for something like libcurl and how you can make use of it. Most of the _"clicks"_ you refer to are apparently web requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These click-related commands are really related to the GUI system. These 'commands' figure out what type of click, where on the screen it occurred, etc. After all that, some function to do the work will start executing, which is completely unique to the program, rather than the GUI.

Program that leverage other programs do not got through the GUI, and therefore can skip all of that. They instead use [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface)'s to directly access the functionality that is accessed by the sequence of events triggered by a mouse click.

The web is not my area of focus, so I do not have a reliable suggestion for how you would accomplish this, but the takeaway is this: Don't strive to understand the underlying technology by tracing mouse clicks. The GUI is an abstraction from what is really going on "under the hood," and is rarely an effective segue into the underlying mechanisms of a program.

Searching for "image search API" would be a good place to start.